# ASP.NET Web API 2 Custom Authorization and Authorize Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

I have created a Google Chrome Extension and I plan to communicate with ASP.NET Wep API 2 service. Web service creates encrypted FormsAuthenticationTicket and sends it in the Login/SignIn response for the first time. Validating user whether is authorized or not has been controlled by checking `Request Cookie`.

Project creates ticket via `GetEncryptedTicket(int UserID)` function.

How can control and use `[Authorize]` attribute above the service functions? I know `oAuth 2.0` may be the better option to implement it but I want to use following function to create ticket.

```
public static string GetEncryptedTicket(int UserID)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        "TICKET_NAME",
        now,
        now.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
        true,
        UserID.ToString(),
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
        );

    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    return encryptedTicket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Action filter to validate the token like this
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (actionContext.Headers.GetValues("UserToken").FirstOrDefault() == null)
            {

                actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    ReasonPhrase = "Http request doesnot have the UserToken header"
                };
            }
            else
            {
                string username = string.Empty, password = string.Empty;

                var userToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("UserToken").FirstOrDefault();
                var token = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(userToken);

                if (token.Expired)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                    {
                        ReasonPhrase = "Invalid User Token"
                    };

                }


            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = ex.Message
            };

        }


    }       

}
```

And Use [BasicAuthentication] Attribute to validate token and allow Access